# Anomaly detection in multivariate time series with autoencoder

Tags: time-series, data-science, autoencoder, anomaly-detection

I have an autoencoder with LSTM layers for anomaly detection in time series.
During the train, the autoencoder learns to reconstruct only the normal sample and then we evaluate the testing set that contains anomalies. If the reconstruction is "too bad" then that time window is an anomaly.

The problem is how to define the threshold during the train. The input has shape (samples, window_size, features) and the error is calculated as the square difference between the true input and the reconstructed sequence.

My problem is how to define a threshold and how to apply that threshold to the testing set. One possible choice is to define one threshold for each feature or one global threshold but I do not know which way is better.

Comment: Use a labeled validation set, and threat the threshold as a hyperparameter

Comment: @JonNordby  My problema is semi-supervised, I have only normal data in training and validation. The loss is MSE between the reconstruction and the input. I know there are many ways to set a threshold e.g mean((x-x_hat)**2) or set a threshold for each feature as np.mean((x-x_recon)**2, axis=(0,1)). Of all these methods, I do not know which is more used in literature.